# How json treats if there is a forward slashes in json string

Tags: c++, json, removing-whitespace, json-lib

I Have a json string as below:

```
[
  {
     "NAME" : "KANTESH",
     "SNAME" : "NAGARADDER",
     "MSG1" : "\"HELLO:HOW ARE YOU\"\n",
     "MSG2" : "\"HELLO:///HOW ARE YOU\"\n",
     "ID"   : 20074499
  }
]
```

when i am trying to remove the white spaces using libjson libarary function i.e json_strip_white_space() i am getting the below resulting string.

```
[{"NAME":"KANTESH","SNAME":"NAGARADDER","MSG1":"\"HELLO:HOW ARE YOU\"\n","MSG2":"\"HELLO:"ID":20074499}]
```

In the above resulting string the characters after the '///' are stripped out and concatenated with next line.

Below are my queries:
1)Why the characters after the forward slashes are stripping out.
2)Does json_strip_white_space() treats '///' as comments
3)How to overcome this problem

Please help me.
Thanks,

Comment: @AlanStokes the question you linked has been removed

Comment: Forward slash has no significance in JSON. There is either a bug in your JSON library, or (more likely) a bug in your code. Can you post your actual c++ code?